# Use windows' SMB to share folder over the internet?

Tags: windows, file-sharing, smb, shared-folders

I wonder if there are any program that can share a folder over the internet using smb? I know that windows has smb file sharing, but it only works on LAN.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to do by enabling ports in the firewall, but implementation defaults are not very secure and most ISPs will automatically block smb for your safety. What you probably want is a virtual Private Network (VPN).

Comment: actually i was able to do so by using samba on Linux. I just don't know how to do it on windows...
I tried VPN, but all connections on mac automatically going through VPN after i connect.

Comment: I ended up using the IPsec/VPN feature of 2 ADSL modem routers to "mesh" the networks together and then used SMB over that

Comment: This topic has aged quite a bit, but for distributing a handful of files or zipped folders, any of the many free storage providers we now have, such as Google Drive, DropBox, etc. are fine. To connect to systems directly over the internet, I find I am using good ol' ssh, scp (secure copy also over ssh), sftp (also implemented over ssh), or fuse-sshfs filesystem in userspace.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of sharing the files is to share media, then a DLNA server would be a better protocol than SMB.   If your sharing files then SFTP (or something like DropBox) is much better performing.

I believe SMB broadcasts share availability out on the network (using UDP ports 137 for WINS and 138 for UDP datagram) and so if your using SMB , your probably asking for trouble.   SMB would obviously also require opening TCP port 445 in the firewall also.  Highly unrecommended.

Also, it is very very difficult to answer your question when you provide so little information about what you are trying to do.