# Mapping a SMB share in Windows

Tags: windows, network-shares, smb

I have a SMB/AFP network share that needs to be accessed via Windows and Mac computers. The AFP side works fine for the Mac OS X clients.

However, I can't get it to map on Windows. I've tried the following steps:

- Right click "Network," select "Map Network Drive"
- Enter the SMB server in the form `\\server.url.here\sharename`
- Select "Connect using different credentials"
- Enter username and password

The window then shows "Attempting to connect" for several dozen seconds, then reverts back to asking for the username and password.

I have tried mapping two different SMB shares in this manner, one running on some version of Windows Server (our university provides this) and another running on Mac OS 10.8 server (the SMB/AFP server) with no success. I have tried on both Windows 7 and Windows 8 (various native and virtualized copies) with no success.

I have already changed the security policy to guest only authentication, which had no effect.

Help? :D

Comment: Are you able to connect to the file share directly by IP address?  For example, in Windows explorer it would be something like **\\192.168.1.1\sharename**.

Comment: No, connecting directly by IP address doesn't work.

Comment: So is this SMB share being done a Linux host or a Mac OS X host?  Also, how exactly are you entering the credentials to connect to this share?

Comment: Mac OS 10.8 host, we're entering the credentials through the dialog that comes up in Windows when you try to map a network drive. Screenshots: http://i.imgur.com/npxLonW.png (server) and http://i.imgur.com/IpJhjGf.png (trying to connect)

Comment: Have you attempted to authenticate with the full computer name credentials on the windows side?  It would look like MAC-HOST\username and then the password?  Here is an example of what I mean:  http://www.andrewhazelden.com/blog/2013/01/connecting-to-a-mac-os-x-lion-smb-share-using-windows-7/

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either. Is there anywhere I can find log files for these? It almost seems like there's an error somewhere, but for some reason, Windows chooses _not_ to annoy me for once... I checked Event Viewer but I have no idea what I'm looking for and there's no search function...

Comment: In that article I linked you the guy says you can check /private/var/log/krb5kdc/kdc.log.  Maybe that will give you some clues?

Comment: Okay, here's a new error: "The mapped network drive could not be created because the following error has occurred: The file cannot be accessed by the system." Hooray for the legendary cryptic error message. I got this message after logging in using a username with the hostname prefixed and _then_ entering just the username/pw combo again _THREE more times_ in the second box that came up. The previous screenshot of the username/pw box has a domain listed (which switches when I explicitly specify it) but the _second_ box does not have the hostname. Also, the time from when I type the...

Comment: ...credentials to when the window reappears gets much faster the last two times.

Comment: I've had so many problems getting the OSX version of SMB to work with Windows in the past, it is such a headache.  Is this the only Windows client or are there others connecting as well?

Comment: We have several Windows users and several Mac users

Comment: Dunno if this helps in your scenario or not but in previous versions of Mac OS there was a cap on the number of concurrent SMB logins, how many users are connected?

Comment: There's no kdc.log in the folder after chmod +rx'ing it to give access. It's empty.

Comment: This is the first user we're trying to connect. :D We have 2 other current AFP connections, so no issues there.

Comment: Great.... ;) Ok, maybe pop open Event Viewer on the Windows box and duplicate the behavior and see if you can get any clues from the Windows side?

Comment: Just thought of something else.  Is the Windows firewall on?  Test if you can connect to the Windows client from the Mac and vice verse over port 445.

Comment: Well, I found the problem. Comcast. I checked router settings but I forgot to actually check the provider... they block port 445 (and also 139). So now the question becomes: is there a way to change the port from the Windows connection side? I can easily redirect the port on the router but I'm not sure how to tell Windows how to use a different port.

Comment: That's a very good question, I've never attempted such a thing...  But I don't think it will be easy.

Answer (score 2):

SMB shares are generally using NetBIOS names, not domain (DNS style hierarchical) names. Try with `\\NETBIOSNAME\sharename`. Make sure your Windows systems have NetBIOS over TCP/IP enabled.

Comment: We're using this over the internet, not just a LAN, so NetBIOS isn't applicable. Also, I should specify again that we can connect, it just fails to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like security is setup on the Host Server.  Please contact the server administrator to obtain the correct user account information.  If the file server is joined to a domain, likely your PC needs to be joined to the domain and your domain account needs to be added to be allowed to access this resource.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about... we're using the correct account information to log into the network drive, which is authenticated by user accounts that reside on the server. I have no idea what "joining to a domain" or "domain accounts" are and how they would affect a simple file server.

Comment: @jfm429 - SMB and AFP are not designed to be used over the internet ([Apple KB Article](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2810952?start=0&tstart=0).) However, if you do want to accomplish this you would need to open some ports on the Firewall between the file server and the internet ([Microsoft KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/204279#appliesto)
 and [Similar Superuser Question](http://superuser.com/questions/409222/use-windows-smb-to-share-folder-over-the-internet).) Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Not exactly, we had the ports open already. We actually solved the problem by using WebDAV and just turned off SMB, so...

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution! If you are concerned with security, however, I would consider SFTP for exposure to external member or a secure VPN solution for an internal contractor or employee [link too WebDAV security discussion](http://serverfault.com/questions/41615/how-secure-is-webdav-is-smb-tunneling-over-ssh-with-putty-a-better-solution)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to setup a Windows user account on Mac using "Options" button available on the File Sharing panel. It allows me to add a User name and chose a password and save.

On Windows, all I did is to Map a network drive with address \192.168.0.xx\ ip address and provide the user name (spaces also possible) and provide the password entered in step 1. It listed all the shared drives to chose from and map to a drive.