# Report disk usage through SMB server

Tags: windows, network-shares, home-networking, disk-space, smb

I have an SMB server (4.5.12-Debian) with several hard drives (all NTFS) attached as my local network backup storage. I would like to be able to see the current disk usage (free space / total space) of the drives. For all i know it's not possible to show that in the Windows Explorer but a regularly updated file on the drives that tells their usage would also work.

I've tried using individual mount points for the hard drives but i still don't see a disk space bar in Windows Explorer ("This PC").

What solutions are there?

Comment: What do you mean by disk usage? Free space? Disk Writes? Disk Reads?

Comment: We need more information - what do you see, what filesystem, what version of samba, etc... You should see disk size and usage in Explorer's bar graphs. If you're using a filesystem like ZFS, then the "_used space_" may be appear to be wonky due to the filesystem hierarchy.

Comment: @DavidPostill i have added all requested information. could the 'on hold' be lifted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using individual mount points and network share points in the Samba configuration and then using the IP adress to connect to the network storage, then map the network share point to a network drive.

Solution found in the comments of this post: [Mapping a SMB share in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/570928/mapping-a-smb-share-in-windows)